# Using a factory to create a derived type

Tags: javascript

I have this base type:

```
function Transition(slide, settings){
  this.slide = slide;
  this.settings = settings;
  this.duration = (this.settings['transitionSpeed'] / 1000) + 's'
}
```

I have a derived type like this:

```
function FadeTransition(){
    Transition.call(this);
}
FadeTransition.prototype = new Transition();
FadeTransition.prototype.constructor = FadeTransition;
```

I have a factory object that I would like to create various derived types:

```
var TransitionFactory = function () {
return {
        createTransition: function (transitionType, slide, settings) {
          if (transitionType) {
            type = transitionType;
          }
         if (type == 'fade') {
            return new FadeTransition(slide, settings);
         };
      },
     //Set default transition
        type: "fade"
     };
};
```

I would like to instantiate my various derived transitions by doing this:

```
 var outTransition = this.transitionFactory.createTransition(currentSlide, currentSlide.outTransition, this.settings);
```

However, I don't get that far, because of this line in my FadeTransition definition:

```
 FadeTransition.prototype = new Transition();
```

I get an error because the `Transition` constructor expects arguments, but when I am assigning its constructor to `FadeTransition.prototype`, I am not passing any in. Should I be somehow?

What is the best way to leverage a factory, and be able to create derived objects with it?

Comment: Replace `FadeTransition.prototype = new Transition();` with `FadeTransition.prototype = Object.create(Transition);`.

Comment: That's good for an answer! I'll mark it as such if you could please provide a brief explanation.